# Print lines from file that contain a string

Tags: python, file, line, display

how do you print a line off a file with a designated condition so for example if there was 251212 on a line how would i get my program to only print that certain line off.
Help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: you can open the file, read each line readlines() that create you an array where each element is a line of your file, then you just search on the array, get the interested position and print only the one that you need

Comment: It's not an array in Python. It's a list. But for all intents and purposes they are exactly the same notations. I know how confusing it can be to understand the data types, especially when different languages call them different names lol!

Answer (score 5):

```
dataLog = []
with open('yourtxtfile.txt', 'rt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    if '251212' in line:
        print(line)
        dataLog.append(line)
print(dataLog)
```

[EDIT BEGIN]
Here's the breakdown;

`dataLog` is a list. We instantiate this variable object so that when we find matches we can store each of them for later processing or reading.

`with open('yourtxtfile.txt', 'rt') as f:`
We open the text file in `rt` mode, which is "read text" and we assign this to the variable `f`.

`data = f.readlines()` the `readlines()` function returns a list object of each line (new line "\n" delimiter) which is stored in the variable `data`.

```
for line in data:
    if '251212' in line:
        print(line)
        dataLog.append(line)
print(dataLog)
```

For each line in the text file, conditionally check if the line "contains" the given string, in this case "251212" and then insert the entire line into `dataLog`

Comment: Why use `__contains__` and not `in`?

Comment: When you call the keyword `in` it invokes the `__contains__`  method. In effect they are one and the same I believe, at least when comparing list values that is.

Comment: Hence my question, why not use `in`? You shouldn't ever call a double-underscore method, those are only meant to define the behaviour of an object relatively to an operator or a generic function. Typically, `in` is there so you don't have to write `__contains__`. Likewise, you'd never call `__add__`, but you'd rather use the `+` operator. Pretty good answer still, although you should not read all the lines then process them. Instead, you should open the file as `f` and directly iterate over `f`. If you read all the lines, you store them in ram, which doesnt happen when iterating over the file.

Comment: You should never write `a.__contains__(b)` instead of `b in a`.

Comment: I agree, check if it str a in str b

Comment: After long deliberation I have edited this post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional in a list comprehension to get only those lines that contain the pattern:

```
pattern = '251212'
matching_lines = [line for line in open('file.txt').readlines() if pattern in line]
print(matching_lines)
```

How it works:

- `open('file.txt')` opens the text file;
- `.readlines()` reads all lines in the file and results in a list of strings, with each string being a line in the file;
- finally, `[line for line in open('file.txt').readlines() if pattern in line]` will select only those lines that contain the pattern.

Comment: Surely you'll need to close the file if you're not using ```with open```?

Comment: Thank you. Most often I don't and let GC clean it up. If you want to be sure it gets cleaned immediately, use `with open('file.txt') as f` instead, and then `f.readlines()` inside the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this; opening the file and reading it line by line, or using subprocess to run `grep` on the string and the file:

Opening the file method:

```
def print_line():
    myfile = open('some_file.txt', 'r')
    for line in myfile:
        if "251212" in line:
            print(line)
```

Or using grep (you may need to pip install `subprocess`):

```
import shlex
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

cmd = "grep %s %s" % ("251212", "some_file.txt")
args = shlex.split(cmd)
process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

result = process.communicate()[0]
print(result)
```

If the file is large, `grep` will be faster, and run it from whatever directory the file is in.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer requires the user to be on an a UNIX like system though? `re` would probably be better than grep in this instance. Then he could use Regular Expressions to find the string in larger files.

Comment: Good point, that completely slipped my mind when writing the answer. If they are on a UNIX like system though they shouldn’t have any issues - I use it myself

Comment: I completely agree. Microsoft missed a trick with grep!

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no one has used `filter` If you want only the lines which contain a certain string then you can use a filter.

```
with open ("file.txt", "rt") as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()

# Data place holder (Remove if you are using a file)
data = ["1", "2" , "251212", "5251212"]

codes = ["251212"]

filteredData = list(filter(lambda x: any(True for c in codes if c in x), data))

print(filteredData)

# OUT: ['251212', '5251212']
```